BIRT: Issue creating reports in MS Word
I am using product which is RCP client with BIRT 8 version and Eclipse 4.23 to generate report in Microsoft Word format. For small data the reports are created without any issue. However, for large data set, the word file is created but is incomplete and I get below exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.wpml.writer.AbstractWordXmlWriter.cropOverflowString(AbstractWordXmlWriter.java:1204)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.wpml.writer.AbstractWordXmlWriter.writeTextInRun(AbstractWordXmlWriter.java:1166)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.wpml.writer.AbstractWordXmlWriter.writeTextInParagraph(AbstractWordXmlWriter.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.wpml.writer.AbstractWordXmlWriter.writeText(AbstractWordXmlWriter.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.wpml.writer.DocWriter.writeContent(DocWriter.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.wpml.AbstractEmitterImpl.writeText(AbstractEmitterImpl.java:1035)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.wpml.DocEmitterImpl.writeContent(DocEmitterImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.wpml.AbstractEmitterImpl.startText(AbstractEmitterImpl.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.wpml.DocEmitter.startText(DocEmitter.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ContentEmitterVisitor.visitText(ContentEmitterVisitor.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.content.impl.TextContent.accept(TextContent.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ContentEmitterVisitor.visit(ContentEmitterVisitor.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ContentEmitterVisitor.visitChildren(ContentEmitterVisitor.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ContentEmitterVisitor.visitCell(ContentEmitterVisitor.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.content.impl.CellContent.accept(CellContent.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ContentEmitterVisitor.visit(ContentEmitterVisitor.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ContentEmitterVisitor.visitChildren(ContentEmitterVisitor.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ContentEmitterVisitor.visitRow(ContentEmitterVisitor.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.content.impl.RowContent.accept(RowContent.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ContentEmitterVisitor.visit(ContentEmitterVisitor.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ContentEmitterVisitor.visitChildren(ContentEmitterVisitor.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ContentEmitterVisitor.visitTable(ContentEmitterVisitor.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.content.impl.TableContent.accept(TableContent.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ContentEmitterVisitor.visit(ContentEmitterVisitor.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ContentEmitterVisitor.visitChildren(ContentEmitterVisitor.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ContentEmitterVisitor.visitContainer(ContentEmitterVisitor.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.content.impl.ContainerContent.accept(ContainerContent.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ContentEmitterVisitor.visit(ContentEmitterVisitor.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ContentEmitterVisitor.visitChildren(ContentEmitterVisitor.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.wpml.DocEmitterImpl.startForeign(DocEmitterImpl.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.wpml.DocEmitter.startForeign(DocEmitter.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterUtil.startContent(ContentEmitterUtil.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableLayoutEmitter.startContent(HTMLTableLayoutEmitter.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterAdapter.startForeign(ContentEmitterAdapter.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterUtil.startContent(ContentEmitterUtil.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.DummyPageBuffer.startContent(DummyPageBuffer.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLLeafItemLM.start(HTMLLeafItemLM.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.resumeLayout(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableBandLM.layoutChildren(HTMLTableBandLM.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLRepeatHeaderLM.layoutChildren(HTMLRepeatHeaderLM.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RenderTask$PageRangeRender.render(RenderTask.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:321)

I tried changing eclipse.ini vm arguments from -Xmx1024m to -Xmx4096m. However, it didn't work.
I would appreciate any pointers to fix the issue. Thanks in advance!

Probably this isn't a memory issue, but a bug.
If you can reproduce it with BIRT 4.15, please create a self-contained report demonstrating the issue and create an issue on BIRT's GitHub site.
Otherwise, you are probably on your own and you can only try to debug the issue yourself (Hint: by adding breakpoints inside the method where the NPE occurs and from where it's called).
In that case, you can probably create and compile your own version of the DocEmitter plugin and use it in your program by just replacing the JAR which contains the emitter.
